# onClickListener is not working within onCreateView method

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Im using the following code to create Floating Action button. Its within a relative layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/form_bg">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_bg_mini"
        app:elevation="4dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/trans_white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how Im setting the onClickListener for the floating action button within onCreateView method.

```
    public class TrendChart extends Fragment {
    private View mRootview;
    private static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/taskstatus.html";
    private WebView chart;

    class InnerWebView extends WebViewClient {
        InnerWebView() {
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript: loadTrendChart();");
        }
    }

    public static final TrendChart newInstance(String company_name) {
        TrendChart f = new TrendChart();
        f.setArguments(new Bundle(1));
        return f;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mRootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trend_chart, null);
        this.chart = (WebView) mRootview.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        this.chart.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.chart.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        this.chart.setWebViewClient(new InnerWebView());
        refreshWebView();

        return mRootview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myFAB);

        myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Clicked","Hello");
            }
        });
    }

    private void refreshWebView() {
        this.chart.loadUrl(URL);
    }
}
```

The problem is that onClickListener is not getting fired. Why is that so? I tried putting listener within onCreateView method too but still the problem persists. Is there any ways through which I can use floating button within a class that extends Fragments?

Comment: Show the code for the enclosing method, where you are initializing the listener.

Comment: Where did you implemented it? Is it in Fragment or Activity?

Comment: Also share the logcat please

Comment: Im implementing it in a class that inherits fragment

Comment: im initialising it within onCreateView method.

Comment: Nothing is getting logged since onClickListener is not getting fired

Comment: @Stanly Try to put it on onActivityCreated();

Comment: Maybe your view isn't the correct layout? View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name, container, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your code when the `Activity` is fully created as follows :

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myFAB);

        myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Check","Clicked");
        }
    });
    }
```

If you have your code on `onCreateView()` your code should look like this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, container, false);

FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.myFAB);
myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do stuff


    }
});
return view;
}
```

### EDIT

Change this :

```
mRootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trend_chart, null);
```

to this :

```
mRootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trend_chart, container, false);
```

Comment: It will work inside onCreate Method. why are you trying in onActivityCreated?

Comment: Please post your full Fragment

Comment: yeah sure..let me try that

Comment: still the same problem persists even after adding `mRootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.trend_chart, container, false);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105540/discussion-between-skizo-and-stanly).